React query v5 invalidation doesn't work some times
I'm using React query v5 in a next.js v14 project. in some cases I need to invalidateQueries(useQueryClient) after mutating and refetch new data. but the problem is that sometimes this invalidation works and sometime doesn't.
for example in 10 times of using invalidateQueries, one time doesn't work.
notice that I'm using react query devtools also.
there an example of my code below 
    mutate(
      { type, staffId, categoryId },
      {
        onSuccess: async (data) => {
          if (data.status === 201) {
            router.push("/checkout");
            await queryClient.invalidateQueries({ queryKey: ["user-basket"] });
          }
        },
        onError: (error) => toast.error(error.message),
      }
    );

I updated react-query once again!
set staleTime and cacheTime to 0!

Have you tried moving the router.push bellow the query invalidation?

Gerardo is right. your router.push would cause the route to change before your waiting for the query to invalidate
